# Regex for matching a tag in a Liquid template : ">" inside html tag

Tags: regex, preg-replace, liquid

I have to write a match pattern for the body tag in a Liquid template.

While matching HTML tags is pretty straightforward, I have the problem that HTML special character can be used inside the Liquid code. 
Example:

```
<body class="template-{{ template | replace: '.', ' ' | truncatewords: 
1, '' }}{% if promo %}has-promo{% endif %} {% if products.size > 1 
%}has-related-products{% endif %} {% if settings.product-hover == 
'quick-shop' %}has-quick-shop{% endif %} loading" >
```

or simplified:

```
<body {% bla > 1 %} bla bla>
```

My current match pattern `/<body(.[^>]*)>/s` matches the above code until the first `>`. I need a pattern that matches the whole  tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
/<body(.[^>{}]*(?:{+[^}]*}+[^>{}]*)*)>/s
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/HwThdM/1)

Instead of `[^>]*` the regex uses `[^>{}]*(?:{+[^}]*}+[^>{}]*)*`, that matches any character but `>`, `{` or `}`; at some point it can meet a `{`, so it matches the whole content of `{+something}+`, followed again by `[^>{}]*`. This trick is repeated many times with the last `*`.

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime".

Comment: @Tom If it's not clear how the regex works please ask.

Comment: @horcrux: I do not understand your regex, please explain :)

Comment: @horcrux: And what if there are nested balanced `{...}`?  Then the regex won't work. Or if there is `{` or `}` in the string literal (like `if settings.product-hover == 
'quick{shop}'`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The OP did not express such a need. In any case, regex don't work with arbitrarily deep nesting. Just a finite level of nesting may be set manually. For instance, [`(?:{+[^}]*(?:{+[^}]*}+[^}]*)*}+[^>{}]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/HwThdM/2) instead of `(?:{+[^}]*}+[^>{}]*)*` is a 2-level nesting

Comment: You are wrong saying PCRE regex can't match arbitrary nested structures, because it supports recursion.

Comment: But I don't think Ruby is PCRE. If recursion works in Ruby, something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/HwThdM/3) is the way.