# How to match a hexadecimal value in liquid templates with regex?

Tags: html, regex, hex, shopify, liquid

**Desired result**

Content editors can enter hexadecimal values in Shopify for a background-color. How can you check with Liquid template's control flow if a given input is a valid hexadecimal?

The regex that needs to be implemented:

```
^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}$
```

The Liquid snippet where it should be added:

```
<div class="a-module" style="background-color: {{ bg_color }};">
  ...
</div>
```

The variable `bg_color` may only be a hexadecimal including the pound `#` character.

How can above be achieved with regex?

**Other solutions?**

If this is not possible what are other methods to match a string in liquid templates?

**Research**

I could not find much about regex in liquid templates.

There is this issue: [Regex for matching a tag in a Liquid template : ">" inside html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778063/regex-for-matching-a-tag-in-a-liquid-template-inside-html-tag)

But I do not understand how it is to be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no regex in Shopify liquid, so there is no way to check it that way.

A better approach will be to use one of the [color filters](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/color-filters).

You can do something like this:

```
{% assign is_color = bg_color | color_to_rgb  %}
{% if is_color %}
  It's color
{% endif %}
```

Where if the color is valid it will return a rgb output, but if it's not it will return a `null` result making the variable false.

If you really need to use regex, the only option is to rely on Javascript and handle it once the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

What about create your own filter. And in this filter checking hexadecimal.

```
/^#[0-9a-f]{3,6}$/igm
```

https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers#create-your-own-filters

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to creating my own filters. I am new to Liquid and I have no Ruby experience, but this does not seem too difficult. I will try it out later.

Comment: I hope it will help you in future. Because custom filters are very helpful in project.